# Repair a broken hard drive?

Tags: drive, error-handling, sector-size

I have a newer Toshiba hard drive with bad sectors... I don't hear anything loose, so I think maybe there is just a scratch in the disk somewhere... I heard of products that can "buff" out those scratches and restore the hard drive into good condition, but I have yet to find one.
Is this even possible?

Comment: are you asking for a softwares or physical products?

Comment: This appears to be a pure hardware problem. Thus it would be suitable for [Super User](http://superuser.com) but is off-topic for [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com).

Answer (score 3):

I don't see how software can do anything about physical damage, and have never heard of anything that claims to.  I have seen programs that test a disk and block bad sectors for use, but the ones I am familiar with are all Windows things that would surely barf on an EXT3 partition if you could get them to run at all.  I suspect there is something already in Ubuntu or available that can do this, but I don't know what it would be.

Comment: *"I have seen programs that test a disk and block bad sectors for use, but the ones I am familiar with are all Windows things .... I suspect there is something already in Ubuntu or available that can do this..."* Linux-based systems have the [`badblocks`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/badblocks.8.html) utility, which can be invoked directly or through [`e2fsck`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/e2fsck.8.html) with the `-c` flag.

Answer (score 1):

As [@user148064](https://askubuntu.com/users/148064/user148064) wrote, software can not repair a hardware problem.

However, any SCSI hard drives and modern SATA drives have spare sectors. (You do not ask them for a specific track, sector and cylinder. You asked them for a sector number. The drive will report itself as "I have X sectors of size Y". Usually the drive actually has a few more.)

When a sector fails to get read or written successfully it will copy that sector to a spare sector and substitute that on all subsequent accesses.

Think of it as a book stating I have X pages with Y chars per page.

> It has a nice index stating:
>   "to read page 1, please turn to page 1",
>   "to read page 2, please turn to page 2",
>   "to read page 3, please turn to page 3",
>   "to read page 4, please turn to page 4"
>   ...
>   "to read page 100, please turn to page 100"
>   etc. etc.

Now you spill coffee on page 3. It *replaces* the index for page 3 with spare page 1.

> The index now looks like this:
>   "to read page 1, please turn to page 1",
>   "to read page 2, please turn to page 2",
>   "to read page 3, please turn to **spare page 1**",
>   "to read page 4, please turn to page 4"
>   ...
>   "to read page 100, please turn to page 100"
>   etc. etc.

*You can trigger* this rereading and remapping process on a drive. That will help if you have any previously undetected corrupted pages (sectors).

However the number of spare pages (sectors) is *limited*.  If you have a groove over the platter then this will not suffice (and that is assuming the head are undamaged, and those are the only likely candidates to make such a groove).

If the source of the failed sectors is something else, then please *consider this as a sign of imminent disc failure*.

**tl;dr:** No software will not repair hardware, though in some cases it can work around the defect.